# inserting data by choosing from one of multiple levels

Tags: r, merge, levels

with 2 dataframes as

```
df1

  num organism tier    A    B    C    D    E
1   1      Ham    1 <NA>    a <NA> <NA>    b
2   1      Ham    1 <NA>    c <NA> <NA>    b
3   1      Sta    1    b <NA> <NA>    a    b
4   1      Sta    1    a <NA> <NA>    a    c
5   1      Sta    1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6   2      Sta    2    c    c <NA>    a    b
7   2      Sta    2    a    c <NA>    b    a
8   3      Ham    3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>


df2

  num tier name
1   1    1  Ham
2   1    1  Sta
3   2    2  Sta
4   3    3  Ham
```

i would like to find the columns which match the num, organism, and tier from df1 and insert the information from df1$A to df1$E.
instead of inserting all the data, is there a way to choose only the highest level?

for example, if levels 'a' > 'b' > 'c',
insert 'a' if 'a' is present,
insert 'b' if 'b' is present wihout any 'a's,
and so on.
lastly, if only NAs or present, insert NA.

my final result should look as

```
df3

  num tier name    A     B    C    D    E
1   1    1  Ham  <NA>    a <NA> <NA>    b
2   1    1  Sta    a  <NA> <NA>    a    b
3   2    2  Sta    a     c <NA>    a    a
4   3    3  Ham  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you even need `df2`. Just `aggregate` after assigning the correct levels to an `ordered` `factor`:

```
ids <- match(c("num","organism","tier"), names(df1))
df1[-ids] <- lapply(df1[-ids], ordered, levels=c("c","b","a") )
aggregate(df1[-ids], df1[ids], FUN = max, na.rm=TRUE)

#  num organism tier    A    B    C    D    E
#1   1      Ham    1 <NA>    a <NA> <NA>    b
#2   1      Sta    1    a <NA> <NA>    a    b
#3   2      Sta    2    a    c <NA>    a    a
#4   3      Ham    3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Ignore the `warnings()` - R just warns that you have taken the `max` of nothing, in the case where you only have `NA` values.